# error in fetching splitted string from rich text box

Tags: vb.net, string, split

help me find the error in this code please. I've spent over an hour looking for it. 
here's the code..

```
Public Class Form1
Dim incomingip() As String
Dim incomingopt() As String

Private Sub btnloadall_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnloadall.Click
    Timer1.Start()
    rtb.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Increment(5)
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 10 Then
        sPort.Write("get ip" & vbCr)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 20 Then
        Call btnip_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 30 Then
        rtb.Clear()
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 40 Then
        sPort.Write("get opt" & vbCr)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 50 Then
        Call btnopt_Click(sender, New System.EventArgs)
    End If
    'If ProgressBar1.Value = 40 Then
    '    rtb.Clear()
    'End If

    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
    End If
End Sub
```

in here, every time I write something in rtb, I always clear it, so the variables won't read the first ones that appear.

```
Private Sub btnip_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnip.Click

    incomingip = stringOfRtb.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray) ''vcrlf splitter
    ''ip parameters
    ip = incomingip(2).Split("="c)
    txtIP.Text = ip(1)

    ip = incomingip(3).Split("="c)
    txtMask.Text = ip(1)

    ip = incomingip(5).Split("="c)
    txtHost.Text = ip(1)

    ip = incomingip(4).Split("="c)
    txtDfg.Text = ip(1)

    ip = incomingip(10).Split("="c)
    txtBackupIP.Text = ip(1)

    ip = incomingip(1).Split("="c)
    cboDhcp.Text = ip(1)


End Sub
```

it now displays splitted strings from rtb to different text boxes just fine..

```
Private Sub btnopt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnopt.Click
    incomingopt = stringOfRtb.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray) ''vcrlf splitter
    opt = incomingopt(0).Split("="c)
    txtJointimer.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(1).Split("="c)
    txtReplace.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(2).Split("="c)
    txtDeviceID.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(3).Split("="c)
    txtPassword.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(4).Split("="c)
    txtFormat.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(5).Split("="c)
    txtSignal.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(6).Split("="c)
    txtAverage.Text = opt(1)
End Sub
```

and this event displays the same strings! even though I declared different instances, this event gets the strings from the btnip. Which is not the one I want to get from this. its like I used incomingip in here. am I not seeing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. It seems that

```
Public stringOfRtb as String = Form1.rtb.text
```

from a global class does not overwrite its data. as from a comment from other people here, it is really better to declare inside a function done using it global. here's what I did..

```
Private Sub btnopt_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnopt.Click
    Dim rtbOpt As String = rtb.Text
    incomingopt = rtbOpt.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray) ''vcrlf splitter
    opt = incomingopt(0).Split("="c)
    txtJointimer.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(1).Split("="c)
    txtReplace.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(2).Split("="c)
    txtDeviceID.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(3).Split("="c)
    txtPassword.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(4).Split("="c)
    txtFormat.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(5).Split("="c)
    txtSignal.Text = opt(1)

    opt = incomingopt(6).Split("="c)
    txtAverage.Text = opt(1)
End Sub
```

now it works.